# Trying to Grep Multiple Phone Numbers Around a Specific Time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep

I work in at a telecom company and in some cases I need to search for multiple numbers around a specific time. I am using **Ubuntu sever 10.04**. When I search for a call my normal expression is:

```
grep 5555551234 20120719-12*
```

Where  `20120719-12*` is the date and time (GMT) for the number I am looking for.

When I use

```
grep 5555551234 20120719-18* | 5555551235 20120719-18*
```

I will only get a return on the first number

If I use

```
grep 5555551234 | 5555551235 20120719-18*
```

I receive `-sh 5555551235 not found`

Any feedback would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

The pipe character (`|`) has special meaning to both grep and your shell.  Use quoting to make sure the shell passes it to grep unmangled.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

In your specific case you can use:

```
grep -E '(5555551234|5555551235) 20120719-18'
```

Notes:

- `-E` tells grep to use `extended regular expressions`
- Don't forget the `'`
- Do not put the `*` in the end of the expression

Just to clarify why you have that error: `|` is a pipe what basically means `sh` will redirect the output of the first application to the input of the second, in this case `5555551235`, but `sh` can't find `5555551235`, so the error.